# call yahoo weather api with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, yahoo-api

I want achieve following functionality.

when browser hits `localhost:3000/weather` server goes to router defined with "weather" mount path.

In order to get data from yahoo weather api should I call it in that route with superagent or proxy is needed for this?

Comment: you can directly trigger http request from your `weather` route.

Comment: @AdityaParab can u please tell me how to trigger http request from there. Do I need to use superagent ?

Comment: Please check answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn more about `request`[on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

First do

```
npm install request
```

then, in your routes files, say `index.js`

```
router.get('/weather', function(req, res, next){
    request('http://www.yahoo.com/your/api/url', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
            res.send(body); // this will send data to client.
        }
    })
});
```